# React app that has 25+ videos/images - extremely laggy page

Tags: reactjs, image, performance, google-chrome, video

I have a react app that loads some very high quality images and videos to display on the page - about 25-50 image/videos. The app runs extremely slow sometimes - as if my computer was old/low-end, which it is not.

Granted, if there are no tabs open except for the react tab, or its freshly restarted the lag is less, but on other computers such as old mac's its very noticable.

An example is scrolling: when scrolling down, the whole page lags for multiple seconds before rushing to finish the scroll.

What could be the problem here? How do you optimize react to have 25 videos/images/gifs playing on the page and not be extremely hard on the CPU/GPU?

Some of these are even lazy loaded but the bandwidth issue is not really a problem, but instead the actual CPU/GPU lag.

Netflix has no lag when being used and its very similar to what I have on my react app. A grid style of multiple images and videos and gifs.

Note this is using chrome.

In total the 25 images/videos is around 250mb to load. But the page only renders the content once fully loaded, so its not the network load time that this question is about - but the rendering of the content after its been fully loaded making the page/app very slow and laggy (since its playing 25 gifs/videos/images)

Comment: Check your network log in dev tools. How big are those videos and images?

Comment: In total its about 250mb to load all of these. Although the network loading is not the issue - its the rendering and displaying of the content once loaded over the network

Comment: Yeah but it could be difficult for browser to play 25 4k videos and render 50 8k images at the same time - thats why I am asking. Do they start playing or being rendered at the same time?

Comment: Its a random mix of videos, images, and gifs. And yes the videos and gifs automatically start playing. But is there something in react that can be done to make the performance better to handle playing this content on the page is the question here

Comment: That might be the problem. You can try to implement [intersection observer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intersection-observer) and start them only if they are in viewport. Also consider lazy loading for images/videos. There might be another problems - like animation/transition over video makes difficulties for browser too etc..

Comment: Interesting, thanks I'll look into intersection observer - this is exactly what I was thinking about is de-rendering them once out of the view. What do you mean about animations or transitions though? What would a transition be? We don't have any animations running.